# .NET web socket returns a 200 error

Tags: c#, javascript, websocket

[This simple web socket example](https://alexjmackey.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/websockets-with-asp-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11/) is returning a 200 error.

Edit: I am reposting the code in C# in hopes that more people will be able to advise me on why I'm having this issue.

I am running VS2012 Express, on my local IIS Machine, the project is configured for 4.5.1 framework and I have imported the Nuget Microsoft.Websockets package.

The three pieces of code I have included below are the only three pieces of code in the project and I have made no modifications to the rest of the project.

There is no break before the unexpected error, it does not break on open or on message on either side. The 200 comes up as an error in the chrome console, but there is no response preview.

Here is the client (index.htm):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>


    <body>
    <input id="txtMessage" />
    <input id="cmdSend" type="button" value="Send" />
    <input id="cmdLeave" type="button" value="Leave" />
    <br />
    <div id="chatMessages" />
    </body>


    </html>
```

and the client script (test.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var name = prompt('what is your name?:');

    var url = 'ws://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.replace('index.htm', 'ws.ashx') + '?name=' + name;

    alert('Connecting to: ' + url);

    var ws = new WebSocket(url);

    ws.onopen = function () {
        $('#messages').prepend('Connected <br/>');
        $('#cmdSend').click(function () {
            ws.send($('#txtMessage').val());
            $('#txtMessage').val('');
        });
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        $('#chatMessages').prepend(e.data + '<br/>');
    };

    $('#cmdLeave').click(function () {
        ws.close();
    });

    ws.onclose = function () {
        $('#chatMessages').prepend('Closed <br/>');
    };

    ws.onerror = function (e) {
        $('#chatMessages').prepend('Oops something went wrong<br/>');
    };

});
```

Here is the generic handler (ws.ashx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Web.WebSockets;
namespace WebSockets
{
    public class ws : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
                context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new TestWebSocketHandler());
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class (TestWebSocketHandler):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Web.WebSockets;
namespace WebSockets
{
    public class TestWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler
    {
        private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();
        private string name;

        public override void OnOpen()
        {
            this.name = this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["name"];
            clients.Add(this);
            clients.Broadcast(name + " has connected.");
        }

        public override void OnMessage(string message)
        {
            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} said: {1}", name, message));
        }

        public override void OnClose()
        {
            clients.Remove(this);
            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} has gone away.", name));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the detail of the 500 error? It often comes back with a hint of what the error is, a description.

Comment: There is no description, or I don't see it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't come up with an error to any effect of this problem, but I found the error which Chrome failed to return alongside my 200 response.

I simply had to turn on the WebSocket protocol under Control Panel --> Programs --> Turn Windows Features on or Off --> IIS --> Application Development Features --> WebSocket Protocol.

At very least I've added a simple VB.NET WebSocket to the site.

Just make sure you have IIS 7+ and are running windows 8 in the 4.5 Framework...and to turn on the WebSocket feature above.

Comment: Shouldn't that be IIS 8+?

Answer (score 0):

The 200 code is not an error, it's the HTTP OK response, which is what you want. Inspect the response using your browser, is there content in the response? Try to add a break point on your ws.onmessage to see if it fires up.

Comment: Well, it is returning a 200 Unexpected error as an "error" in the Chrome console, but that is more or less what I expected. I'll try breaking the onmessage.

Comment: The response has no preview, and neither the ws.onmessage nor the method in the class breaks on a breakpoint when initiated before the error is returned via ws.onerror

Comment: It also does not break onopen

Comment: Despite not fully answering my question, you were the first to try and you were quite helpful in terms of what the response was doing. I answered it myself, even though it was ridiculous. Enjoy the bounty.

Comment: Thanks! I did forgot about WebSocket being security restricted, that explain why you did get a 200 code but still got an error.

Answer (score 0):

simply just check on the web socket protocol form add or remove programs

go to **Control Panel**

---

then click on **add or remove programs**

---

then **Turn Windows Features on or Off**

---

then **IIS**

---

then **Application Development Features**

---

then check the check box of  WebSocket Protocol option

---

i tested it on **Microsoft windows server 2012**

Answer (score -3):

I found this in wikipedia:

200 OK
Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The actual response will depend on the request method used. In a GET request, the response will contain an entity corresponding to the requested resource. In a POST request the response will contain an entity describing or containing the result of the action.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm not sure how this helps me with respect to websockets.